# PosixFileFunctions.stat fails with UnsatisfiedLinkError in Linux for Gradle 2.3

Tags: java, gradle, java-native-interface, build.gradle

gradle build fails in my DEV environment. My colleagues have the same configuration as that of mine but it works fine for them. Also, I was able to execute the build command successfully last week.

Environment configuration:

```
Gradle 2.3
Groovy: 2.3.9
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM: 1.8.0_73 (Oracle Corporation 25.73-b02)
OS: Linux 2.6.32-300.3.1.el6uek.x86_64 amd64
```

Task:

```
task updateLibraries {
   delete "lib/compile"
   delete "lib/test"
   // error at the line below
   copy {
       from configurations.compile.copy()
       into( 'lib/compile' )
    }
    copy {
       from configurations.testCompile.copy()
       into( 'lib/test' )
    }
 }
```

Error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Build file '/home/user/ProjectName/build.gradle' line: 303

What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ProjectName'.

net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.PosixFileFunctions.stat(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/rubygrapefruit/platform/internal/FileStat;Lnet/rubygrapefruit/platform/internal/FunctionResult;)V
Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Exception is:

org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ProjectName'.
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:154)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:492)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:86)
at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:169)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.PosixFileFunctions.stat(Ljava/lang/String;Lnet/rubygrapefruit/platform/internal/FileStat;Lnet/rubygrapefruit/platform/internal/FunctionResult;)V
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.jni.PosixFileFunctions.stat(Native Method)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultPosixFiles.stat(DefaultPosixFiles.java:30)
at net.rubygrapefruit.platform.internal.DefaultPosixFiles.getMode(DefaultPosixFiles.java:46)
at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.NativePlatformBackedStat.getUnixMode(NativePlatformBackedStat.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.nativeintegration.filesystem.services.GenericFileSystem.getUnixMode(GenericFileSystem.java:61)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileTreeElement.getMode(DefaultFileTreeElement.java:67)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTreeElement.copyTo(AbstractFileTreeElement.java:76)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultFileCopyDetails.copyTo(DefaultFileCopyDetails.java:104)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction$FileCopyDetailsInternalAction.processFile(FileCopyAction.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:65)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1$1.processFile(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.processFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:60)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyFileVisitorImpl.visitFile(CopyFileVisitorImpl.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTree$1.visitFile(AbstractFileTree.java:145)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.SingletonFileTree.visit(SingletonFileTree.java:43)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.collections.FileTreeAdapter.visit(FileTreeAdapter.java:96)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.AbstractFileTree$FilteredFileTree.visit(AbstractFileTree.java:136)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.CompositeFileTree.visit(CompositeFileTree.java:54)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:37)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecActionImpl.execute(CopySpecActionImpl.java:24)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec$DefaultCopySpecResolver.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:498)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DefaultCopySpec.walk(DefaultCopySpec.java:322)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DelegatingCopySpecInternal.walk(DelegatingCopySpecInternal.java:206)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.process(CopySpecBackedCopyActionProcessingStream.java:36)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:44)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator$1.process(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:56)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopyAction.execute(FileCopyAction.java:35)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.execute(NormalizingCopyActionDecorator.java:52)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.execute(DuplicateHandlingCopyActionDecorator.java:42)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.CopyActionExecuter.execute(CopyActionExecuter.java:38)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopier.doCopy(FileCopier.java:64)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.copy.FileCopier.copy(FileCopier.java:49)
at org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFileOperations.copy(DefaultFileOperations.java:125)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.copy(AbstractProject.java:746)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScript.copy(DefaultScript.java:169)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.DefaultScript.copy(DefaultScript.java:165)
at build_3o7k207plxbmxd2hy7hl6sbsq$runclosure22.doCall(/home/user/ProjectName/build.gradle:303)
at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:130)
at org.gradle.util.ConfigureUtil.configure(ConfigureUtil.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.configure(AbstractTask.java:488)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.task(AbstractProject.java:851)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:225)
at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
at build_3o7k207plxbmxd2hy7hl6sbsq.run(/home/user/ProjectName/build.gradle:299)
at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
... 32 more
BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Are you running a 32bit JVM on a 64bit machine?

Comment: `java -version` returns me this: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a standard library needed by the JNI libraries is not installed on your machine (hard to believe).

```
cd /tmp
unzip ${your_gradle_home}/lib/native-platform-linux-amd64-0.10.jar
cd net/rubygrapefruit/platform/linux-amd64
ldd -v libnative-platform.so
```

Check if one of the libraries is not installed/found.

For each dependency (on the left) there should be a valid reference on the right

```
either: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe209dc000)
or    : libstdc++.so.6 => /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f1206b7e000)
```

if you see something like (for example)

```
libstdc++.so.6 => not found
```

it means you need to install the package (of your Linux distribution) which provide the `libstdc++.so.6`.

Comment: I am not able to see `not found`. Instead, I see this:
`linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff06d7b000)` `libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fa84d692000)`
`libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007fa84d40d000)`
`libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fa84d1f7000)`
`libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007fa84ce63000)`
`/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d6c200000)`

Comment: @SumeetDas If in the whole ouput of `ldd -v ...` is no `not found` that means all libraries for the 64bit `libnative-platform.so` are in place. So something further to check: **1)** that there is no other `libnative-platform.so` in the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, **2)** that gradle really use the JDK you expect, **3)** run gradle with `--debug` to get more information